# Can the ? operator be defined for types other than Option and Result?

Tags: rust

The question mark operator (?) is defined for Option and Result types. Is it possible to overload it for some custom type? I haven't found any trait that might guide this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

The trait you're looking for is called [`std::ops::Carrier`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.17.0/std/ops/trait.Carrier.html). However as you can see it's experimental and it caused lots of discussions on how to implement it (I believe it's experimental for a few years already).

So technically you may use it, but you better don't rely on it as its look might be changed or it can be removed for good.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I've looked for.

Comment: It has been [`std::ops::Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) for a while now, but the semantics haven't changed, its still not a stabilized feature.